# Limit max users in ejabberd MUC

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

As I can see in [xep-0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#registrar-formtype-owner) there is option to limit max users in room:

```
<field
      var='muc#roomconfig_maxusers'
      type='list-single'
      label='Maximum Number of Room Occupants'/>
```

I'm using Smack lib for Java to create rooms. And I send form during creation process like this:

```
[...]
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("3");
submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_maxusers", list);
[...]
muc.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
```

And it doesn't work. In one room I can see 4 ppl, for exmple, but server shouldn't accepted 4th invite, right?

Other options (`muc#roomconfig_persistentroom`, `muc#roomconfig_membersonly`, etc.) work fine. There is the problem only with `muc#roomconfig_maxusers`.

I'm using last version of ejabberd.

How can I limit max users in MUC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It isn't possible to set custom value for this option. You can check [sources](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/mod_muc_room.erl#L58). Possible values are: `[5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000]`.

2) Admins doesn't count. So, if you have 5 ppl in room (1 of them admin), 1 man still can join this room.